# Weka Logistic Regression Output (Gender)

Tags: data-mining, weka, logistic-regression

I'm running logistc regression in Weka against a dataset which contains an attribute "Gender" whose members can be {Male,Female}.

I understand the other cofficients in the output, but what does it mean when "Gender" is +0.7647? Is it favoring male or female?

On the preprocess screen, Male comes before Female in the attribute information. Does this mean I am to interpret that LR says being Female increases the probability of class membership?

**Edit**

I added an example of the output hiding some of the other attribute names.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your output (or a similar example)?  I am confused as to where you see "Gender" +0.7647.  In the mean time, does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136213/how-to-interpret-weka-logistic-regression-output/19139376#19139376

Comment: Is it possible that you are not predicting the gender class?  I guess this because it seems to be used in your regression model.  In the preprocess screen, look for a drop down box near the bottom right hand corner (above the visualization).  Does it say "Class: What Gender?"?

Comment: I'm not predicting the gender class. I'm predicting another class. I'm trying to interpret what the 0.7467 means in this output. Does it mean MALE is favored for the "entry" class? Or does it mean FEMALE is favored for the "entry" class?